# SQL SERVER 2008 R2 Identity Range

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, merge-replication

The current table I am having issues with has an Publisher Range Size of 10,000, but when I look at the constraint I only see 1000 for the range size at the publisher. I have tried running sp_adjustpublisheridentityrange and changing the Publisher Range Size to 12000 to kick start it, but it still will not change.

Comment: Are you trying to change the identity_range or the pub_identity_range?

Comment: pub_identity_range

Answer (score -1):

I manually changed the identity fields with DBCC CHECKIDENT.  No automated way or configuration to fix it.